# Remove a collection from a collection

Tags: php, laravel, collections, laravel-5

I've been building a custom ticket system for my Laravel application, and users can place comments on their tickets.

When a new comment is placed, I want to send a notification to everyone involved in the ticket.

Users can be involved if they are:

- the ticket owner
- the agent assigned to the ticket
- invited as a participant to the ticket

To do this, I am creating a collection of users and then looping through them to notify them. The only issue with this is that it currently includes the person making the comment too, and they don't need to be notified as they were the ones leaving the comment.

I've tried to [`filter`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-filter) the collection to remove the user if the id matches the currently logged in user, but this doesn't seem to work:

```
$ticket = App\Ticket::findOrFail(1);

//Create collection to hold users to be notified
$toBeNotified = collect();

//Add the ticket owner
$toBeNotified->push($ticket->owner);

//If an agent is assigned to the ticket, add them
if(!is_null($ticket->assigned_to)) $toBeNotified->push($ticket->agent);

//Add any active participants that have been invited
$ticket->activeParticipants()->each(function($participant) use ($toBeNotified) {
    $toBeNotified->push($participant->user);
});

//Remove any duplicate users that appear
$toBeNotified = $toBeNotified->unique();

//Remove the logged in user from the collection
$toBeNotified->filter(function($user) {
    return $user->id != Auth::user()->id;
});

//...loop through each user and notify them
```

Upon further reading, I think this is because you use `filter` to remove an element from a collection, rather than a collection that is inside a collection.

**How can I remove a user from the collection if they are the currently logged in user?**

When I `dd($toBeNotified)` after running the above, this is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `except` to achieve this.

```
$toBeNotified = $toBeNotified->except(auth()->id());
```

As a side note you should use merge when you want to add more than one user.

```
$toBeNotified = $toBeNotified->merge($ticket->activeParticipants);
```

The filter method you use is correct as well, but it returns the filtered collection while keeping the original collection unchanged.

```
$toBeNotified = $toBeNotified->filter(function($user) {
    return $user->id != auth()->id();
});
```

Edit: The `except` would work only when you have an eloquent collection.

Comment: `except()` will not work, as it excludes an item based on the key in the collection and the key is not related to the user's id. It would work if you first did a `keyBy()` to key the collection by the user's id, though.

Comment: @patricus I've used `except` just a week back in this project https://github.com/gothinkster/laravel-realworld-example-app/blob/master/database/seeds/DummyDataSeeder.php#L111 and i know for sure it works. I've even gone ahead and written a test for you to check for yourself. Not sure if you made that comment without even bothering to test. Check my updated answer.

Comment: @Sandeesh thanks for this. I implemented `merge()` to clean the code up a bit and used `filter()` but as you pointed out I am altering `$toBeNotified` to actually be set to what is returned. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @james glad i could help you and thanks for confirming :)

Comment: @Sandeesh I will grant you that the usage in your package will work, and the usage in the test you provided will work, but it will not work for the usage shown by the OP. The difference is that you are working on a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`, whereas the OP has created a plain `Illuminate\Support\Collection`. Calling `except()` with a model's key will remove that model from an Eloquent Collection, but it will not remove that model from a standard Collection. You can see this yourself by adding `->toBase()` in your test: `$users = factory('App\User', 5)->create()->toBase();`

Comment: @patricus thank you for teaching me that, i've used `collect` very little and was under the impression that pushing models would behave the same way with them. I've tested out what you've said and you're absolutely right. Cheers!